# How to find the relationship chain in Python or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

There is create table SQL:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for test
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of test
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (2, 6);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (5, 2);
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Table Looks like: 
 id      pid
 1         2
 2         6
 2         3
 3         4
 4         5
 5         2
I want to output :

- 1-2-6
- 1-2-3-4-5

Don't loop

What should I do, use Python or MySQL ?

Comment: It seems odd that and id can have 2 pids eg 2,6 and 2,3 is there some rule for picking 2,3 in the second row of your result?

Comment: I'm not sure about `python` but you can easily achieve this with `recursive cte` in MYSQL 8.0 onwards. Which version of MYSQL are you using?

Comment: @P.Salmon looks like where there's more than one choice, you get separate rows with each

Comment: @ysth yeah I get that, I just don't see a rule for picking 2,6 or 2,3

Comment: If you have MySQL8 or mariadb 10.2, use a recursive cte.  If not, you can still do it with a bunch of repetitive self joins, but only up to the limit of 61 joins

Comment: @P.Salmon it doesn't pick, it follows _both_, with each unique chain being a separate row

Comment: @ysth This result is already used by MySQL8 cte.  I want to more than 61 joins.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy This table is already used MySQL8 cte.

Comment: Add that to the question and show what the rest of the larger query looks like, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way

```
with recursive cte (id, pid ,path) as (

  select     id,
             pid,
                         CAST(1 as char(255)  )  as path

  from       test
  where      id = 1
  union 
  select     p.id,
             p.pid,
                    CONCAT(cte.path,',',p.id)  AS path

  from       test p

  inner join cte
          on (p.id = cte.pid and cte.pid <> 1 and FIND_IN_SET(cte.pid,cte.path)<1 )

)

select  id,pid ,CONCAT(path,',',pid) FROM cte;
```